# SQL count all the column, sum it, and display The Last 3 row in ASC order

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to count all of the column in my table that has value >= 10.
here is my table:

```
 Date#####   |  Value1 |  Value2 |   Value3
 23/04/2014  |  1,2    |    12,3 |    10  
 23/04/2014  |  11,2   |    3    |   10,3     
 24/04/2014  |  10,9   |    3    |     1
```

I want it to display:

```
 Date#####   | Count 
 23/04/2014  |  4  
 24/04/2014  |  1
```

Assume that I have a lot of group of date, I want it to display only the last 3 group of date.

here is my first code :

```
Dim strCommand As String = "Select Date, count(*) as tcount 
                            from tbBooth 
                            having count(*) >= 10 
                            group by date"
```

already changed based on the solution from Collapsar into this:

```
Dim strCommand As String = "Select t.d, sum(t.valcount) cnt 
                            from (select [date] AS d, 
                                         CASE WHEN t1.Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 
                                              ELSE 0 END + 
                                         CASE WHEN t1.Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 
                                              ELSE 0 END + 
                                         CASE WHEN t1.Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 
                                              ELSE 0 END AS valcount 
                                   from tbBooth t1) t 
                            group by t.d"
```

it's works, but I want to display only the last 3 row based on `ASC` order.
Is there anyway how to do it?

Comment: you need to use `limit` to limit number of rows returned..

Comment: SELECT TOP 3....ORDER BY Date

Comment: Dear Siva,,
I added LIMIT 3 after from tbBooth t1 from my code but it give me the error : Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Comment: Dear Mihai,
I can't use SELECT TOP 3 because I want the last 3 rows in ASC not the first 3 row.

Comment: First, you should not be storing comma delimited values in a column in your SQL Server database.  You should read about referential databases and how to properly use them.  Second, you are not "counting" dates, rather you are counting values > 10 and grouping by date.  Is that what you want?  It's unclear from your post whether April 23rd should be counted twice or four times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT d, cnt
FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP 3 [date] AS d, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                   CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                   CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
  FROM tbBooth
  GROUP BY [date]
  ORDER BY [date] DESC
) x
ORDER BY d ASC
```

Comment: it's works.... thank you Sir... you really helped me.
I put the SELECT TOP on the wrong side before.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear t-clausen, may I ask another question Sir. I add column type on my table to differentiate it again. There are two type :  Yes, and No after I add another group using your code above. I want to alias the YES group as TYES and NO group as TNO, is it possible to do that Sir? Thank you Sir.

Comment: @user3567963 Your request doesn't make sense. Not unless you want to count the YES and NO. Try reading about "group by"